# How to extract values from json array and validate in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I am new to Splunk, trying to fetch the values from json request body. I am able to fetch values one by one by using

**"json_extract(json,path)"**

but I have more than 10 fields so I am trying to use

**"json_extract(json,path1,path2..pathN)"**

which is returning the json array.
But I am not getting how to read the values from json array and check if it is null or not.

```
eval keyValues ="json_extract(json,"firstname","lastname","dob")"   
| table keyValues


output: ["testfirstname","testlastname","1/1/1999"]
        ["testfirstname","testlastname",null]
        [null,"testlastname",null]
```

Can someone please help how to ***loop above json array*** and check the value, if it is null or not(eval isnotnull(firstname))

Comment: What does your sample data look like? Is it already being extracted as JSON by Splunk when it's ingested?

Comment: you are  correct it's already extracted from json, just I want to loop the array and read the values .

Answer (score 0):

if your events are in JSON and it is easily accessible through field names then I suggest using the Spath command like below. Just replace your condition with YOUR_REQUIRED_CONDITION.

```html
| makeresults 
| eval json="{ \"firstname\": \"firstname123\", \"lastname\": \"lastname123\", \"dob\": \"1/1/1999\"}" 
| spath input=json
| where YOUR_REQUIRED_CONDITION
```

You can also go with your approach but here you have to extract the same 10 fields and need to compare them as per your requirements, see the below code.

```html
| makeresults 
| eval json="{ \"firstname\": \"firstname123\", \"lastname\": \"lastname123\", \"dob\": \"1/1/1999\"}" 
| eval keyValues =json_extract(json,"firstname","lastname","dob")
| table keyValues
| eval keyValues = json_array_to_mv(keyValues)
| eval firstname=mvindex(keyValues,0),lastname=mvindex(keyValues,1),dob=mvindex(keyValues,2)
| where YOUR_REQUIRED_CONDITION
```

**If you share your SAMPLE events and the exact where conditions with us then we can provide the optimum solution.**

Thanks
KV

Comment: Is there any way to write below command dynamically, based on the size I should get the values: like for(int i=0;i<length;i++){ mvindex(keyvalues,i); }| eval firstname=mvindex(keyValues,0),lastname=mvindex(keyValues,1),dob=mvindex(keyValues,2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the values, you need to treat them as multivalue fields, and expand/filter appropriately

For example:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp fieldname.subname{}.value=*
| rename fieldname.subname{}.value as subname
| mvexpand subname
| stats count by subname
| fields - count
```